# Unfinished Stubbing Exception when injecting wrapped class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am getting the following error while mocking with mockito:

> Method threw
> 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException'
> exception. Cannot evaluate
> util.DocumentHelper$MockitoMock$1355901941.toString()

Here is the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class EurLexHtmlToHtmlServiceTest {

@Mock
private DocumentHelper documentHelper;

@InjectMocks
private EurLexHtmlToHtmlService eurLexHtmlToHtml;

@Test
void urlToHtmlSetUpCorrectStyle() throws IOException {

    private final String url = "https://someUrl.com/";

    Map<String, String> params = ImmutableMap.of(
            "url", url,
            "hasOnlyOneSheet", "false",
            "hasBorders", "false"
    );

    Mockito
            .when(documentHelper.getDocument(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(new Document("src/test/resources/eurlexTest.html"));

    assertThat(eurLexHtmlToHtml.urlToHtml(params))
            .hasContent("<style>test</style>");
    }
}
```

DocumentHelper is a wrapper of Jsoup:

```
@Component
public class DocumentHelper {

public Document getDocument(String url) throws IOException {
    return Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    }
}

@Service
public class EurLexHtmlToHtmlService extends BaseHtmlToHtml {

final DocumentHelper documentHelper;

private static final String eurlex_URL = "someUrl";

public EurLexHtmlToHtmlService(DocumentHelper documentHelper) {
    this.documentHelper = documentHelper;
}

@Override
public InputStream urlToHtml(Map<String, String> params) throws IOException {
    Document document = documentHelper.getDocument(params.get("url"));
    Element content = document.body();
    return getInputStream(document, content, eurlex_URL);
}

public abstract class BaseHtmlToHtml implements HtmlToHtmlService {

@Autowired
HtmlLayout htmlLayout;

@Autowired
DocumentHelper documentHelper;

protected InputStream getInputStream(Document doc, Element content, String url) throws IOException {
    Element cssLink = doc.select("link").last();
    String cssHref = cssLink.attr("href").replace("./../../../../", "");
    Document cssDoc = documentHelper.getDocument(url + cssHref);
    Elements cssElements = cssDoc.getAllElements();
    content.append("<style>" + cssElements.outerHtml() + "</style>");

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(content.outerHtml().getBytes());
    outputStream.close();

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

I guess that the issue might come from the fact that the method getDocument() is called twice, but event though trying some workaround it did not help

Following comments, I am using:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

java.lang.NullPointerException
at cz.cvut.kbss.htmlexporter.service.urlToHtml.UrlFileToHtmlService.urlToHtml(UrlFileToHtmlService.java:35)
at cz.cvut.kbss.htmlexporter.service.urlToHtml.UrlFileToHtmlServiceTest.urlToHtml(UrlFileToHtmlServiceTest.java:44)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Comment: Can you share what versions you are using?

Comment: Can you also share the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes no problem, I also updated it :)

Comment: What is `url` in your test? (In `params` map)

Comment: Just a string, which is a web link